# any way to view a deleted answer?

Tags: feature-request, answers

I made a question yesterday, and someone did answer something, 
I remember i asked for more information in the comments, but today I checked again and the user deleted the answer.
Wich makes me feel like i'm crazy or something, but no, i'm sure he (or she) actually did answer my question.

There should be something like a record for the questions you ask. Something like a history, or a log where you can check if this kind of things actually happened.

of course, it should be visible only for the author of the question, not for everyone.
I think in most of cases it would turn out to be useful

I don't know if this feature already exists, but i couldn't find it.
Thanks for your help, despite this may be more of a suggestion for the site

Comment: I think only mods with a link can see deleted things

Comment: [Users with over 2000 rep can also see deleted answers](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (here is a [screenshot](http://pasteall.org/pic/68684) of the answer in question, I hope the OP doesn't mind..) Note that there is a history of both the question and answer(s), however deleting is not included in this (unless the post is later undeleted).

Comment: I didn't know about that, thank you!. AND thank you for the screenshot, it was actually a very useful answer and it is the approach i'm using right now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Users with over 2000 rep can also see deleted posts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Here is a screenshot of the answer in question, I hope the OP who deleted it doesn't mind..

[image]

Note that there is a history of both the question and answer(s), however deleting is not included in this (unless the post is later undeleted).

To view the history of a post, click the date/time below it.